# Is there a theorem that says that a function between finite dimensional spaces has a matrix representation?

Tags: linear-algebra

Just the line in the question. Is there an actual theorem that states this or is it something that people just know.

If there is such a theorem I would like to be able to cite it, that's the purpose of this question.

Comment: Well it's not true. **Linear** functions between finite dimensional vector spaces have a matrix representation. This is a **theorem** which is easy to prove.

Comment: An arbitrary function or a linear function? If the latter then yes; this should be in any serious linear algebra book (Lang, Axler, Hoffman-Kunze, Halmos, ...)

Comment: This follows (if the function is linear) from the fact that every finite dimensional linear spaces is isomorphic to $\Bbb R^n$ or $\Bbb C^n$. Since every linear map $T:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^m$ can be represented by a matrix (after fixing the bases), the fact follows immediately.

Comment: @Hoot Arbitrary. Dang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f: E\to F$ is linear yes and the matrix representation is given to a basis as follow :

Let $(e_i)_{i\leq n}$ be a basis of $E$ and $(g_j)_{j\leq m}$ is a basis of $F$
then we calculate $f(e_i)$ for all $i$ and we give their expression in the basis $(g_j)$ 
and if we put :
$$
A=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
  f(e_1) & f(e_2) & \dots & f(e_n)\\
\end{array}\right)
$$
then for all $x\in E \qquad Ax=f(x)$.
as example : if we take $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R^2}$ such that
$$
f(x,y)=(x+y,x-y)
$$
then 
$$
f(e_1)=(1,1)\\
f(e_2)=(1,-1)
$$
so 
$$
A=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
  f(e_1) & f(e_2) \\
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
  1 & 1\\
1 & -1
\end{array}\right)
$$
we can prove using that representation that every matrix represent a linear mapping. So for general fonction we can't have this representation.

Comment: for general case what we can do is (as in the real analysis) to give a linear "approximation" of the function, this what we call differential calculus and the matrix representation of the "approximation" is called Jacobian matrix